# npm kafka-node: Close consumer after final message read

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka

I want to write a function that will call a callback once the last message in a topic has been read.

```
function getCurrentMessages(kafka, topic, cb_done){
  // Start consuming from the beginning
  var consumer = new kafka.Consumer(new kafka.Client(), [{topic: topic, offset: 0}], {fromOffset: true});
  consumer.on('message', function(msg){
    // Do something with msg
  });
  consumer.on('final-message-received', function(){
    consumer.close(function(){
      cb_done();
    });
  });
}
```

Is this possible with the current library?  I don't want to leave the consumer open to receive new messages.

Comment: Is your goal to just read all the messages on topic and exit? If so, have you considered using different technology?

Comment: Also why would you need to keep the consumer, how about you exit after you are done?

Comment: I do not need to keep the consumer.  I want to know how to exit after I'm done.  I still want to use Kafka because some consumers will be persistant, but others need to read a snapshot, which is what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with the help **offset**. You can easily get the information of event offset in the Consumer side.
KAFKA provides you below mentioned offsets :

> **1. Earlier offset 
>
>   2. Current Offset and 
>
>   3. Latest offset**

You just need to get the latest or the offset of last message written in Kafka and compare it with the current offset while consuming event, in that case when you consume last message from kafka you will have latest offset equal to current offset.
You can write a IF condition where you will check

> IF(current_offset == latest_offset) 
> {
>       
>      Break the flow or the action which you want;  
> }

Please let me know if it doesn't work for you or need any further information.

Comment: I can get the latest offset by passing -1 in for Time here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol
However, I don't see a call to get the current offset.  When processing messages, I see the offset of the message, but the last message on the topic has an offset number lower than the latest offset.  One hack would be to check if the current message offset is equal to one less than the latest offset, but if I message gets purged for any reason, this may not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
consumer.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log("received message", message);
        if(message.offset == (message.highWaterOffset -1)){
          consumer.close(true, function(err, message) {
            console.log("consumer has been closed..");
          });
        }
 });
```

Comment: Basically message object contains current offset and last offset. For every message read from topic, it checks if this is the final message in the topic. If so, close the consumer and return.

Comment: Does the close function actually close the consumer or the connection to Kafka